# How to cut a pdf page with text,and add the page(PdfImportedPage) to another pdf file

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a pdf, I read it with `PdfReader` and get one page of the pdf with `PdfImportedPage`.

Then I want to get a subpage of the  page, with `BufferedImage.getSubimage`,
but I don't know how to cut the `PdfImportedPage`.

My code is below:

```
PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(name1);
//get one pdf page i 
PdfImportedPage page1 = PdfWrite.getImportedPage(pdfReader1, i);
//add to another pdf file 
conByte.addTemplate(page1,0,0);
```

Comment: `BufferedImage.getSubimage` is an awt method for bitmap images. A `PdfImportedPage` effectively is a PDF XObject which may containany combination of bitmap and vector contents including text. Thus, you cannot apply `BufferedImage.getSubimage` to a `PdfImportedPage`.

Comment: What you can do, though, is setting a clip path before adding the template which hides everything outside from view (but not from copy&paste or text extraction). Or you can even redact those areas away to also prevent copy&paste and text extraction. Thus, which of these options do you wish to implement?

Comment: how to zoom the page（PdfImportedPage）？

Comment: Look at the other `addTemplate` overloads; many of them allow to apply an arbitrary affine transformation, e.g. a scaling.